# Solr 5.2.1 core load fails

Tags: solr

After I re-installed solr 5.2.1 and put the same core that worked for the previous installation of the same version of solr, I tried adding the core, both by using the "new core" dialogue and the URL http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD

I got the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:347)
at java.util.TreeMap.containsKey(TreeMap.java:232)
at java.util.TreeSet.contains(TreeSet.java:234)
at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleReloadAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:768)
at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestInternal(CoreAdminHandler.java:239)
at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:193)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:660)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:431)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:227)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What do I need to change to get the core loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RELOAD command seems to missing the "core" parameter.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=core0
```

See https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-5.2.pdf